# Windows 7 Applications keep taking exclusive audio control

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm running the Win7 Beta.
Applications keep stealing exclusive audio control.
For instance, every time Trillian makes a noise everything else is muted (even if noise levels continue in the mixer).

Similarly, playing a game like Defcon which uses DirectSound stops my media players making any audible noise.  This is not true for other games so just seems to be something that some applications do.

I've unticked "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device" for all sound devices.

I've also set "When Windows detects communications activity" to "Do nothing".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Check your sound card driver is up to date and properly supported under Windows 7. Has this worked before under Windows Vista? If so then it ought to work in 7. Try moving to the Release Candidate as well as the Beta build is quite old now - infact, shouldn't it have been disabled by now?

Comment: I agree, it sounds like a driver issue. The RC or RTM is the best bet, or alternatively new audio drivers.

Comment: Yep, I am running the RTM with an X-Fi gamer PCI sound card and it works perfectly.

Comment: Okay, I thought it was a Win7 feature gone awry.  Never ran this system under vista but it's pretty new so I wouldn't have thought it was a big issue.  I'll try moving to RC/RTM when I get a chance.  Thanks!